# How to override conventions used for foreign key names in in Entity Framework Core 7+?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

EF Core 7 introduced a semi-straightforward way to manage "Model Building Conventions" ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#model-building-conventions)) but I am struggling to identify the appropriate way to leverage that (or something like it) to change how EF Core 7 auto-determines column names when creating many-to-many skip navigation tables.

I'll provide an example with some made-up names; ignore whether the names are "conventional"/"good" as they are just to illustrate the concrete situation and I'm making them up on the spot.

Let's say I have entity "Book"

```
public class Book {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Author> ContributingAuthors { get; set; } = new():
}
```

And entity "Author"

```
public class Author {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Book> BooksWritten { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And I relate them in my `onModelCreating` method as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>
    .HasMany(book => book.ContributingAuthors)
    .WithMany(author => author.BooksWritten)
    .UsingEntity("AuthorBookCrossReference");
```

EF Core will go ahead and create the many-to-many (join) table `AuthorBookCrossReference` and will give it two columns: `BooksWrittenId` and `ContributingAuthorsId`. I would prefer that it instead give it Ids corresponding to the table names, or entity names -- either way, really. I'd prefer to see `BookId` and `AuthorId`.

Does anyone have an idea about whether there is an "appropriate" way to do this, perhaps leveraging the new Model Building Conventions paradigm?

The way I am doing right now, and is not my favorite because I have to do it per-column and it feels very "magic numbersy" is something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("AuthorBookCrossReference").Property("BooksWrittenId").HasColumnName("BookId");
```

This works, but I'd prefer a more elegant approach if it's out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up names for the table and columns using [`CollectionCollectionBuilder<TLeftEntity,TRightEntity>.UsingEntity<TJoinEntity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.collectioncollectionbuilder-2.usingentity?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-collectioncollectionbuilder-2-usingentity-1(system-string-system-func((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder((-0))-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-referencecollectionbuilder((-0-0))))-system-func((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder((-0))-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-referencecollectionbuilder((-1-0)))))) overload as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#joining-relationships-configuration). Something along this lines:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>
    .HasMany(book => book.ContributingAuthors)
    .WithMany(author => author.BooksWritten)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "AuthorBookCrossReference",
        j => j
            .HasOne<Author>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("AuthorId"),
        j => j
            .HasOne<Book>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("BookId"));
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that is a way to go. It feels verbose and redundant for how little I want to actually configure, but it does do away with needing knowledge of current naming conventions. I'm still curious to know if there is a way to utilize Model Building Conventions to drive how EF Core auto-names foreign keys, because that would save me probably many lines of code when all is said and done.